# Mobile first css not working on small screen

Tags: css

I am trying to make my font color change on different screens

For default small mobile screens, I have done this

```
.mytext {
   color: red;
  }
```

For tablets,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
 .mytext {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

For Desktop

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .mytext {
     color: green;
      }
    }
```

Here, on the desktop screens, color turns to green which is fine, but the color red never shows up even on really small screens (below 500px), it just turns yellow when decreased below 992px. Shouldn't the tablet view be restricted between 768px and 992px only?

Comment: what is the color when below 500px?

Comment: its yellow below 768px

Comment: Mention the source code, at least the order in which these codes are written.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had forgot to include the viewport in the head. Sorry.

Comment: put that line in the answer, and mark it as correct